# How to handle SSL certificate error in windows phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

Basically I want to ignore SSL Certificate error and display a pop-up dialogue .
Phone is displaying error as below, How do I invoke "WebBrowser_LoadCompleted" method ,since the method is not being called after getting SSL error.

[image]

This is my code

> Xaml:

```
 <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="WebBrowser" />
```

> C# code:

```
InitializeComponent();
WebBrowser.Loaded += WebBrowser_Loaded;
WebBrowser.LoadCompleted += WebBrowser_LoadCompleted;


private void WebBrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        //popup dialogue
    }

   private void WebBrowser_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string uriString = "https://.....";
        Uri uri = new Uri(uriString);
        this.PaymentBrowser.Navigate(uri);
    }
```

Please help..

Is there any other alternative or webBrowser on which this might work...

Comment: Are you set IsScriptEnabled="true". Reply if work or not i think i know whats the reason

Comment: And also check for you system date and time and emulator time settings , true to debug in physical device if possible

Comment: From my past experience,I think you cannot override ssl check in wp8. As far as your trying to load https it need a valid certficate

Comment: Can you please let me know how to get the valid certificate